# Copy files in one file with filename using Batch

Tags: batch-file

Hello I want to copy some .csv files into one file including an entry with the filename, like:

```
hello.csv:
1; 2; 3
wolrd.csv:
4; 5; 6
```

Should result in:

```
Datei.csv:
hello; 1; 2; 3
wolrd; 4; 5; 6
```

For only copying the data

```
type *.csv >> data.csv
```

work but I am missing the filename. Sorry I am very new to Batch scripts. Bash would be no problem, but this has to work on Windows

**EDIT:**
To be more specific: I have a folder with this .csv files and I want every file to be copied in this form into one file!

Comment: what about csv's headers? Are they the same and is there need to be trimed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "root_dir=c:\csv_files"

pushd "%root_dir%"

del /q /f united.csv >nul 2>&1
break>united.tmp

for %%# in (*.csv) do (
    echo %%#
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%#") do (
        (echo(%%#;%%a)
    ) >>united.tmp
)

move united.tmp united.csv
```

Change root_dir to the directory where the csv files are.